# J sort function: 1/:1 returns 0

Tags: sorting, j

In the degenerative case, sorting just one number in J

```
2/:2
```

gives (correctly)

```
2
```

but why

```
1/:1
```

gives (incorrectly)

```
0
```

?

Comment: Also,
   
    #$ 2 /: 2  result shape is 1 (list)  as expected

   #$ 1 /: 1 result shape is 0  (atom), not a list as expected. I have asked on J forums to see if any answers pop up.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug in some J versions. The correct is of course `1`.

Comment: The comments in the J forum concur with this. The discussion can be found here: http://jsoftware.com/pipermail/programming/2015-April/041487.html